# how to write 'Ashutosh' in japanese language?

Tags: translation

how to write a Indian name '**Ashutosh**' in Japanese language??

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thank you,

Shilpi

Comment: At a guess: アシュトシュ?

Comment: There is a mangaka called _tosh_ and he writes it in Japanese as とっしゅ. Maybe sounds better this way.

Comment: I don't know how the name would be pronounced in its native language, so an IPA transcription would help. Going by how an English-speaking person would expect it to sound, I would say アシュトッシュ.

Comment: @Kurausukun I don't know what Indian language Shilphi Singh speaks, but I think <Ashutosh> might be pronounced /ˈəʃʊtɔʃ/.

Comment: **アシュトシュ** means ashutoshu and **アシュトッシュ** means Ash Tosh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Nothing at all](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/9971/nothing-at-all) has posted in comments the correct spelling would be 
`A-shu-to-shu` in katakana. `アシュトシュ`.

From my first semester in Japanese it was taught that foreign names always used katakana characters whereas native names always use hiragana/kanji characters.

Comment: thanks for ur answer....so which on is correct  
**アシュトシュ  or アシュトッシュ**      ???

Comment: The first one is according to my instructor. I showed her your question. Currently sitting in my third semester class.